# Writing content to files with "foreach" loop in powershell

Tags: powershell, foreach

TASK:
Need to update all files in a directory with new information. First we find the content then replace it in all files.

ISSUES:
When updating the files, the data from other files is appended to the next file.

EXAMPLE:

Original file content:

file1

```
net use /persistent:no

net use p: \\houfilesvr01\company

net use s: \\houfilesvr01\shared
```

file2

```
net use /persistent:yes

net use T: "\\houfilesvr01\advanced pharmacy"

net use R: "\\houfilesvr01\Advanced Pharmacy\Account MGMT"

net use S: "\\houfilesvr01\Advanced Pharmacy\Implementation"
```

Post update content:

File1 & file2

```
net use /persistent:yes

net use T: "\\aps.local\advanced pharmacy"

net use R: "\\aps.local\Advanced Pharmacy\Account MGMT"

net use S: "\\aps.local\Advanced Pharmacy\Implementation"

net use /persistent:no

net use p: \\aps.local\company

net use s: \\aps.local\shared
```

---

The desired changes are being made, but the changes are being written to each file. We do not want that!

---

```
<# Variable Declaration  
$find - Values to replace
$replace - replacemtn values
$filepath - path of files
$content - content of existing files
$newcontent - updated content to write back to file 
#>
<# Variable Assignment #>
    $find = "houfilesvr01"
    $replace = "aps.local"
    $filepath = "C:\Users\jshabazz\Documents\Area51\logonscripttesting\Testfiles\*.*"
    
<# execution #>
    
    foreach($file in $filepath)
        {
             $content = get-content $file
             $newcontent = $content -replace 'houfilesvr01', 'aps.local'
             set-content -Path $filepath -value $newcontent
             
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You must *enumerate* the input files based on your *wildcard path*, using [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem).
- Pass only a *single* path to [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content) and [`Set-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content).

```
foreach($file in Get-ChildItem $filepath) {
  $content = get-content $file.FullName
  $newcontent = $content -replace 'houfilesvr01', 'aps.local'
  set-content -Path $file.FullName -value $newcontent           
}
```

<sup>Note: Using the `.FullName` property is the safe thing to do in *Windows PowerShell*, where the [`System.IO.FileInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.FileInfo) instances output by `Get-ChildItem` *situationally* stringify to only file *names*. In *PowerShell (Core) v7+* this is no longer necessary, because unconditional full-path stringification is now ensured.</sup>

---

As for **what you tried**:

- Since `$filepath` is just a *string*, `foreach($file in $filepath)` doesn't *enumerate* anything, it essentially just copies that string to variable `$file`.
- Both `Get-Content` and - perhaps more surprisingly - also `Set-Content` directly accept wildcard paths as their (positionally) implied `-Path` arguments, in which case they read from / write to *all matching files*.